# Modifying null column to not null

Tags: sql-server, database

How to make a NULLABLE column to NOT NULL in SQL SERVER. I made a table with four columns:

My table:

```
id int null
fname varchar not null
last name not null
contact int null.
```

Now what i am required is to make id column to be not null.So please help me how we can make a null column to be a not null column.

Comment: Are all current ID values not null?

Comment: yes.The values in the column are not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following statements to do it. Change the name of column id as required

```
UPDATE [Table] SET id=0 WHERE id IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN id INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

Replace [Table] with the name of the table

Answer (score 1):

first Update `id` Column '0'(Zero) where `NULL` then right Click on table then select Design and  uncheck Allow Nulls checkbox of your `Column` from sql table design.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tableName

ALTER COLUMN columnName nvarchar(200) [NULL|NOT NULL]
```

Comment: this won't change the id column at all. How does it answer your question?